# Call a service from ionic after payment success

Tags: angularjs, symfony, ionic-framework

Hi I have integrated PayU Money gateway in my ionic app. The issue is after paymment success I want to call a service to the server to update payment status but its not calling service inside a function as:

```
function iabLoadStop(event,$ionicLoading,$http) {    

if (event.url.match("https://payu.herokuapp.com/success")) {    

    iabRef.executeScript({
        code: "document.body.innerHTML"
    }, function(values) {

        alert(values);

        //incase values[0] contains result string
        var payId = getValue(values[0], 'mihpayid');
        var response = getValue(values[0], 'status');
        var c = getValue(values[0], 'unmappedstatus');          

            //Calling function pyament status
            updatePaymentStatus($ionicLoading,$http,payId,response);


    });

 iabRef.close();
  }
}

function updatePaymentStatus($ionicLoading,$http,payId,response){ 

var apiUrl = 'http://148.251.158.141/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/web/app_dev.php/api/';

         $http.post(apiUrl+'student/result/term',{

                            studentId: '56456456466',
                            term: 'Term1'

                        }).then (function (res){  alert(res);


                            if (res.data.ResponseCode == "1") {

                                        //$scope.showp("Message","Massage Send  successfully","Okay")
                                        //$state.go('dashboard')
                                } else if(res.data.ResponseCode == "0"){
                                    //$state.go('login')
                                }
                        })

}
```

So in above code the statement:

```
$http.post(apiUrl+'student/result/term',{});
```

is not working.please assist what could be the issue in this

Thanks advance

Comment: are you sure you are using ionic 2? [`$ionicLoading`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicLoading/) is an ionic v 1 component..

Comment: Yes I run ionic -v then its show me 2.2.2

Comment: no..that is the ionic cli version.. check package.json for ionic package version

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: its "version": "1.1.1",.

Comment: any idea why above services is not get called ?

Comment: i havent used version 1 of ionic.. Some one with exp will answer..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144804/discussion-between-sunil-rawat-and-suraj).

Answer (score 0):

just pass the transactionId to the updatePaymentStatus

```js
if (event.url.match("https://payu.herokuapp.com/success")!== -1) {    
        //Calling function pyament status
     updatePaymentStatus($ionicLoading,$http,$scope.transaction.id,response)   
        $scope.goBack = false;  
        iabRef.close();
}
```